# Click event not triggering CSS pointer-events: none

Tags: jquery, css

I have two images stacked one above the other. `img_top` has 'pointer-events: none' set, so clicking on it will pass the click to `img_bottom`. However if I invoke jQuery's `trigger('click')` on `img_top`, the click will not pass on to `img_bottom`.

Can anybody explain why and find a way of passing the click to the bottom image using jQuery's `trigger('click')` AND CSS's `pointer-events`?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #img_holder {
        position: relative;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    #img_bottom {
        position: absolute;
        background: url('/images/cross.png');
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #img_top {
        pointer-events: none;
        position: absolute;
        background: url('/images/tick.png');
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
            $("img_top").trigger('click');
        });

        $("#img_bottom").click(function() {
            alert('success');
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="img_holder">
    <div id="img_top"></div>
    <div id="img_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in javascript events bubble up the DOM. `img_bttom` is a sibling of `img_top`, so the event would never bubble to it.

You can force it manually though:

```
$("#img_top").click(function(event) {
    $("#img_botton").trigger(event);
})
```

Comment: This works correctly, but why doea a "real" click then pass through? And how to emulate it?

Comment: @AdrienHingert a real click passes through because it is handled by the browser's UI, which looks at mouse position and determines the correct element to raise the event on.

Comment: Is there any way that this can be "faked" via JS in such a way that it would pass through as per my example above?

Comment: I would need it to go through one image with the pointer-events set to none. Your example skips this.

Comment: You say in the OP `img_top has 'pointer-events' set to none, so clicking on it will pass the click to img_bottom. However if I invoke jQuery's trigger('click') on img_top, the click will not pass on to img_bottom.` This code fixes that problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18526/discussion-between-adrien-hingert-and-rory-mccrossan)